# Area Between the Curves for $\ln (x)$ and variants

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

I have 4 curves, and I need to find the area between the curves.

- $\ln x$
- $\\|\ln x|$
- $\ln |x|$
- $\\|\ln |x||$

[image]

Comment: Good luck, then. And what was your question?

Comment: I need to find the area enclosed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\ln x\mathrm{d}x=x\ln x-x\bigg|_0^1=-1$$
$$Area=-4\int_0^1\ln x\mathrm{d}x=4$$

Comment: I think he is asking for the area, not integral value. If he asks about integral value, I think the answer is 0.

Comment: @user5722540 For all we know, you didn't solve anything, you conveniently preferred to ask for a solution, here.

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts, let $$f(x)=\ln x\implies f'(x)=\frac1x$$ and $$g'(x)=1\implies g(x)=x$$ Then $$\int_0^1\ln x\,dx=[x\ln x]_0^1-\int_0^11\,dx=-1$$ Since each of the four quarters are identical, we have that the total area is $$I=4|-1|=\color{red}{4}$$